# How to express "I hope" in "it is" sentence pattern?

Tags: word-choice, idiom-requests, sentence-patterns

I want to use "it is...that" sentence pattern to express the same meaning as "I hope that..". The first thing to come to my mind is "it is my hope/wish that ...", but that sounds quite weird.
So how am I supposed to alter "I hope that.." into the "it is..that.." pattern? What word should I choose? As far as I can imagine the candidates are "hope", "wish" and "expectation", but none of them seems to sound right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"It is my hope" is not unusual. A quick search with Google gets over 7 million hits on that exact phrase.

The less personal "It is to be hoped" is also common.

Comment: Thanks! yes I just found "it is my hope" in COCA, it should be ok

Comment: Doesn't '"It is my hope" is not unusual. A quick search with Google gets over 7 million hits on that exact phrase.' make this general reference?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Google isn't a reference in itself, so no. I don't know if you can find _it is my hope that…_ in an actual reference work, but I would guess probably not. I would say this is not GR, though I find it strange that the asker used the phrase and apparently dismissed it without even checking to see if it should be dismissed or not.

Comment: @Janus 'Over 7 million hits' would seem to veer towards authority. If this is not accepted, this answer is totally unsubstantiated. _Something_ needs downwhotsiting.

Answer (score 0):

"It is what I hope for as I answer my first question on this board" is my answer.

In the the context of "it" referring to increasing reputation points, this also has the benefit of being a true statement.